# Adding a querystring to Ngx-Translate When Loading Language Files from External Content Sources Without Page Reload

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I'm using ngx-translate to manage internationalization in Angular 12 and I'm using an API to retrieve my language files which is working fine, but I'm not sure how to pass additional parameters to the API to do additional logic to decide on the right language file.

Here is my current setup:
in my **app.module.ts**

```
.
.
.

    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        })
      ]
.
.
.

export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(
    httpClient,
    'http://translation-service.remote.com/',
    ''
  );
}
```

You can see that I'm calling a remote endpoint **http://translation-service.remote.com/** which will return to me the language json file

And here is what I have in my **app.component.ts**

```
    export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public translate: TranslateService){
    translate.addLangs(['en-us', 'en-gb']);
    translate.setDefaultLang(`en-us`);
  }
}
```

And finally from my **app.component.html**

```
   <select #langSelect (change)="translate.use(langSelect.value)">
      <option *ngFor="let lang of translate.getLangs()" [value]="lang" [selected]="lang === translate.currentLang">{{lang }}</option>
    </select>
```

When the application loads or when the user selects a language, ngx-translate sends a request that looks like this: [http://translation-service.remote.com/[select-language]](http://translation-service.remote.com/%5Bselect-language%5D) (e.g. http://translation-service.remote.com/en-us)

Now, I want to be able to pass a query string parameter to the translation api GET request. for example: http://translation-service.remote.com/en-us?extraParam=abc without having to reload the page, but I couldn't find a way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by creating a custom `TranslateLoader`, to be used instead of `TranslateHttpLoader`, then handle any custom behavior within it, like the following:

```js
export function HttpLoaderFactory(
  httpClient: HttpClient,
  helperService: HelperService
) {
  return new CustomTranslateHttpLoader(httpClient, helperService);
}

export class CustomTranslateHttpLoader implements TranslateLoader {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private helperService: HelperService) {}

  getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
    // Fetch the translations from the server if the extraParam is provided, otherwise return empty object.
    if (this.helperService.extraParam) {
      return this.http.get(
        `http://translation-service.remote.com/${lang}?extraParam=${this.helperService.extraParam}`
      );
    } else return of({});
  }
}

// Your module
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forChild({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient, HelperService],
      },
    }),
  ],
})
```

Where `HelperService` is a service that you can use to pass the `extraParam` to the `CustomTranslateHttpLoader`:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class HelperService {
  extraParam = 'abc';
}
```

And in your component, you can handle the language change like the following:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss'],
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(
    private translateService: TranslateService,
    private helperService: HelperService
  ) {}

  onLangChanged(lang: string) {
    // change the extraParam that will be used within CustomTranslateHttpLoader's getTranslation:
    this.helperService.extraParam = 'YOUR_EXTRA_PARAM_HERE';

    // Reset the selected language, and delete the inner translation, to be loaded again once `use` function is called:
    this.translateService.resetLang(lang);

    // Use the selected lang, which will cause the CustomTranslateHttpLoader to load the translation again because the `lang` is reset above.
    this.translateService.use(lang);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer Amer. I'm new to Angular, so I wonder if I will be able to make the "extraParam" be read from the UI? say I want to change it according to a user selection to a comboxbox ... isn't the code you shared will be executed once, being the module?

Comment: Could you please explain the whole scenario of this use case? So I can make my answer more helpful. Thanks.

Comment: The user on the UI selects a language, and also selects an environment name. The translation will be fetched from the server using both these two parameters. that's why I need to make sure both will be sent, and not just the language

Comment: So, the user will be at the beginning, on a landing page, where he can select the language, then after selecting the language he will be redirected to the other pages, right?

Comment: No, they won't be redirected. They can select the language, or select the environment, and either of these selections, will trigger the translate module to pull the translations from the server endpoint. I hope that makes sense

Comment: I updated my answer based on your feedback, hope you will find it helpful.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much. Only comment is that it seems that calling this.translateService.use(lang); after this.translateService.reloadLang(lang); is redundant and causes two calls on the network to the same resource. I've ended up using this.translateService.reloadLang(lang);  only

Comment: Thanks for your note. Could you try to remove `this.translateService.reloadLang(lang)` and keep the `this.translateService.use(lang)` only, but with changing the return of `CustomTranslateHttpLoader` to `of(null)` instead of `of({})`, and let me know if it works or not, please. Thanks.

Comment: Actually that's not the problem, my requirement is that I need to fetch the language if the environment changes. So take this scenario: The user loads the page > we fetch language (en) and environment (x) ..if the user changes the environment to (y), the translate module won't contact the server again if we use the use() function, because it already has the (en) language cached I think. Hence, the reloadLang() function seems to guarantee the call to be made. Although it makes me lose that built in caching functionality, but that's OK.. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Thanks, I thought there won't be any loaded lang at the beginning. Anyway, using `reloadLang` only will not change the `translateService.currentLang` property which is used to get the translation when you call `instant`/`get` functions or `translate` pipe.
So calling the `resetLang` function, then `use` function, will be better in your case than using `reloadLang` only. Check it please, and let me know if it's okay for you.

Comment: Indeed, thanks a lot, I switched to the (resetLan & use) combo

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround for this scenario is to manually load and set the translation file.

```
this.httpClient.get('http://translation-service.remote.com/en-us?extraParam=abc').subscribe( translationFile => {

   this.translate.setTranslation('en-us', translationFile )
   this.translate.use('en-us')   
})
```